# Error with faces-config.xml and primefaces-sentinel.taglib.xml when using primefaces premium theme

Tags: xml, jsf, primefaces

I am using a Primefaces Premium theme I added the necessary jars to its classpath but encountered an error I could not debug because it seems to be not java related but xml/jsf related

**faces-config.xml**

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>       - cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'primefaces-sentinel' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '($|*|
>        \p{L})(\p{L}|\p{Nd}|*|$)*' for type 'null'.
>       - cvc-complex-type.2.2: Element 'name' must have no element [children], and the value must 
>        be valid.

**primefaces-sentinel.taglib.xml**

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'description'. One of '{"http://
>    java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":handler-class, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":behavior, "http://
>    java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":component, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":converter, "http://
>    java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":validator, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":source}' is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unfortunate that you didn't show the code causing the problem. So it's guessing based on the error messages.

> **faces-config.xml**
>
> > Multiple annotations found at this line: - cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'primefaces-sentinel' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '($|| \p{L})(\p{L}|\p{Nd}||$)*' for type 'null'. - cvc-complex-type.2.2: Element 'name' must have no element [children], and the value must be valid.

So, you have in `faces-config.xml` the below element?

```
<name>primefaces-sentinel</name>
```

Given the regular expression pattern `($|| \p{L})(\p{L}|\p{Nd}||$)*`, the hyphen is indeed invalid in the `<name>` element.

Remove the hyphen or use a different name matching the given pattern:

```
<name>sentinel</name>
```

---

> **primefaces-sentinel.taglib.xml**
>
> > cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'description'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":handler-class, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":behavior, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":component, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":converter, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":validator, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":source}' is expected.

The `<tag-name>` is missing in list of expected elements, so you have in `primefaces-sentinel.taglib.xml` the below ordering?

```
<tag>
    <tag-name>...</tag-name>
    <description>...</description>
    ...
</tag>
```

Given the expected element ordering as defined in the XSD file, this is indeed invalid.

Swap around them:

```
<tag>
    <description>...</description>
    <tag-name>...</tag-name>
    ...
</tag>
```

Comment: All errors was gone in eclipse!  Just one thing that confuses me is that those 2 issues that I corrected using your solution were not issues in Netbeans do you have any idea why it works totally fine with netbeans but not in eclipse?

Comment: Apparently Netbeans doesn't validate XML files against the declared XSD. I can't tell why as I've never really used Netbeans.

Comment: Thank you Ill keep that in mind sir atleast its alot clearer to me now why they are behaving differently.